# How can I get rid of P-SEP boxes that appear on some of my webpages?

Tags: javascript, html, windows, google-chrome

[image: P-SEP1[![][1]]][2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tFs3E.jpg)

As far as I know, the P-SEP box only appears in Google Chrome on Windows OS. It does not appear on any browser on Mac OS, or on any mobile device. I did see a suggested solution to add the following javascript, but that didn't work:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").children().each(function() {
        $(this).html($(this).html().replace(/&#8233;/g," "));
    });
});
```

I have no way of viewing this, since I'm using MacOS. The webpage is: https://www.fourseasonsnj.com/

Comment: I'm getting this also, In Chrome/brave brower